# Limited Node References

Tags: nodes

I am building a site for a client where each page has 3 other pages associated with it.
I know how to create node references but I would like to find a way to limit the user to creating just 3 node references per page.

So each page only allows the creation of 3 references and whrn all of them are created the "add reference" link is removed ( until perhaps one or more of the references is deleted ).

Can anyone suggest a potential solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In node reference field settings page (content type -> manage fields -> name of field) in "global settings area" set "number of values" to 3.

Thats it.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! It didn't even occur to me it could be that simple.

Comment: Simple solution is usually the best one. :)

Comment: Just realized the issue which prompted my original post (which I had forgotten :-). Node References offer the 'Global Settings' area but the 'number of values' dropdown list is not included ???

Comment: You'll find it under Home » Administration » Structure » Content types » [Your Content Type Name] » Manage fields